# How to embed Responsive Youtube video in Drupal Bootstrap subtheme?

Tags: theming

I am trying to embed a Youtube video to a block using Bootstraps .embed-responsive-item class. The Text Format is set to Full HTML.

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/zpOULjyy-n8?rel=0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

It’s working just fine on my static html version. However within Drupal the video canvas doesn’t use the full block dimension? What’s the correct way to embed full-size Youtube videos in a Drupal Bootstrap subtheme?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice workaround. It seems like that embed-responsive isn't supported in Drupal Bootstrap subthemes?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with Drupal's Bootstrap theme but I guess not - I think with Bootstrap 3 you can add `img img-responsive` as a class to videos as well to make them responsive, but I'm not certain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s my solution: I was using an outdated CDN version for Bootstrap before 3.2.x. Make sure that you're using at least Bootstrap 3.2.0 or
higher (http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2014/06/26/bootstrap-3-2-0-released

Thus I wasn’t able to use .embed-responsive-item class in my template files. Anyway, Thank you for support and quick workaround!

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

[responsive-youtube-embed](http://avexdesigns.com/responsive-youtube-embed/)

The essential bit:

> You will need to wrap the responsive youtube embed code with a  and specify a 50% to 60% padding bottom. Then specify the child elements (iframe, object embed) 100% width, 100% height, with absolute position. This will force the embed elements to expand fullwidth automatically.